# module 'keras.optimizers' has no attribute 'Nadam'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model

[why showing error here? I was trying to implement VGG16 model but there have an error...!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5o3p.png)

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizers.Nadam(lr=2e-5), metrics=['acc'])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide more details about code like imports etc. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

`keras.optimizers.Adam` 
https://keras.io/api/optimizers/adam/ 
It's a misspelled word

Comment: No, `Nadam` optimizer exists. It is an optimizer with nesterov momentum.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of `keras` and `tensorflow` you are using, you can import Nadams in either way (`keras` is now part of `tensorflow`):

```py
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Nadam
```

OR

```py
from keras.optimizers import Nadam
```

and then use it as:

```py
Nadam(learning_rate=0.0001)
```

Sample usage:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Nadam

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=20, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer=Nadam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Comment: Yeah, Thanks it will work...!! but I have another issue shows in the next line that was

validation_steps = validation_generator.samples // BATCH_SIZE,
InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error: