# UnknownError: Graph execution error: why this was showing an error on here? in Google Colab

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

[here i implement the pre trained model VGG16 Where i fitting the model with 5 epochs it will show Graph execution error...!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qsz7r.png)

```
cnn = model.fit(training_set,validation_data=testing_set,epochs=5,steps_per_epoch=len(training_set),validation_steps=len(testing_set))
```

Comment: The message is incomplete, and never post text as images, only as plain text.

Comment: You've a similar thread running [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73210533/module-keras-optimizers-has-no-attribute-nadam/73217367) for the related problem. You can search this forum for `Graph execution error`. If nothing works for you, then please provide more details like sample data and source code to reproduce the problem. Please read [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).